# Mocking system_clock in unit testing

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

I have unit testcase suite to simulate various timings in day. Is it possible to change system time at the beginning of each testcase using chrono::system_clock?

Comment: Is it feasible to wrap the calls to `system_clock` and mock the wrapper instead so you can completely control the passage of time?

Comment: I recommend writing your own custom chrono clock that does what you need.  If you need it to switch at run-time between `system_clock` and manual, so be it.

Comment: let me come up with my own custom chrono clock and post here :)